# Is it really necessary to check if getBy or findBy methods returns truthy values?

Tags: react-native, react-testing-library, testing-library, react-native-testing-library

I have some experience in frontend projects using testing-library, but definitely I'm not an expert. During the code review process on most of those projects, it was really common to find some test suites with this structure:

```
// Original code: https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/blob/0ede61780bd8788dfa09572643a14c9988c7b92b/examples/reactnavigation/src/__tests__/AppNavigator.test.js#L24

test('clicking on one item takes you to the details screen', async () => {
    const component = (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <AppNavigator />
      </NavigationContainer>
    );

    const { findByText } = render(component);
    const toClick = await findByText('Item number 5');

    fireEvent(toClick, 'press');

    // ---------------- is this neccessary? --------------------

    const newHeader = await findByText('Showing details for 5');
    const newBody = await findByText('the number you have chosen is 5');

    expect(newHeader).toBeTruthy(); 
    expect(newBody).toBeTruthy();

    // ---------------------------------------------------------

});
```

My doubt is if we are not ending up being redundant with this approach to check if an element does exists on DOM...

According to the [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#types-of-queries), if we use `getBy` or `findBy`, it should throw an error when there is no matches. So I assume that there's no way for a `getBy` returns a falsy value, or a `findBy` resolves a falsy value. And if it is true, so maybe we don't need to check it again. Does it make sense?

So I was wondering if it would be really bad if we just do like this:

```
test('clicking on one item takes you to the details screen', async () => {
    const component = (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <AppNavigator />
      </NavigationContainer>
    );

    const { findByText } = render(component);
    const toClick = await findByText('Item number 5');

    fireEvent(toClick, 'press');

    await findByText('Showing details for 5');
    await findByText('the number you have chosen is 5');
});
```

Idk if it makes sense but afaik check if those calls didn't throw error should be enough to validate if an element exists on DOM, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that would be enough in that case. However, for consistency and readability, I find it's better to have explicit assertions (in the form of `expect` statements).

Answer (score 1):

Tossing in the expectations communicates the intent of the test better, even if you're correct that they're not strictly necessary, as Kent Dodds discusses in [this blog post](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#using-get-variants-as-assertions). I don't see any apparent performance penalty to including them, either.

You may prefer to use `queryByText` which will return an element or null and let you write "normal" expects that are called on both success and failure cases. However, `query` doesn't wait for the predicate as `find` does, so you could use `waitFor` to build your own `find`. See [About Queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/) for details on the differences.

If you `expect` an element queried by text *not* to exist, I've found that this can trigger large component object tree diffs that can slow down testing considerably (and serializing circular structures can crash it). You might use `expect(!!queryByText("this shouldn't exist")).toBe(false);` to avoid this scenario by converting the found element to a boolean, with the drawback that the assertion message will be less clear.